# In node, is there any functional difference between these two require styles?

Tags: node.js

I sometimes see in tutorials things written like this:

```
const db = require('../models');
const { sequelize } = db;

const result = await sequelize.query(sqlQuery);
```

But the following version also works:

```
const { db, sequelize } = require('../models');

const result = await sequelize.query(sqlQuery);
```

Is there any advantage to doing it one way or the other?

Comment: Between the examples, `db` may end up with different values. `require` returns whatever single thing the module emitted. In this case, it appears to be an object. In your first example, you're assigning the object to a variable, then using object destructuring to assign one of its properties to another variable. In your second example, you're using object destructuring to assign the returned object's properties to variables.

Comment: Also, you seem to have some typos: `sequelize` and `squelize` (missing `e` in latter)

Answer (score 1):

I think both ways will give the almost same result for the `sequelize`. Because the `sequelize` in both ways is a sub-module of `..models`. But I think the `db` in two ways isn't the same.

In the first example, `db` is present for the whole of the module `models`. Then you call the `sequelize` from `db`, it the same with you call the `sequelize` from module `models` directly.

In the second case, you call the `sequelize` directly

```
const {db, sequelize} = require('../models);
```

This is almost same with the first case. The different thing is you call it from `require` instead of the "const" like the first case. That's why it still works.

But please be careful with the `db`, because the `db` in the second example is a sub module of `models` and the `db` in the first example is the whole of the module. If you show the value of `db` in two ways, you may see the difference.